# How do I prevent repeated iCloud logins when switching boot disk?

Tags: icloud, startup

I've several different APFS bootable volumes. When I restart, and switch from MacOS 13 to 15, or back to 13, after I log into my user account, I'm asked to re-authenticate on iCloud.

It seems that each change in boot disks makes iCloud believe that this is a new machine. This is new behavior since I installed MacOS 15, though I've always noticed that iCloud requires re-authentication more frequently than seems necessary.